# Nuget restoring errors

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I am trying to Build list of Projects, which was developed on MVC3 using visual studio 2012 with .net framework 4.

When I try to Build solution using VS2017, I am getting nuget Package error on restoring it.

I went all the possible solutions-

1. Tried to uninstall and reinstall it.
2. Changed framework and cleaned the solution.

But, still I cannot get rid of the error. Can anyone help me ?

This is the error which I am encountered with

[image: error screenshot]

When I try to reinstall or update or restore it.I am getting following error

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple actually and a common oversight.
If you check,you will find out the visual studio 2017 does not support mvc3.
Update accordingly